# asp.net error "format of the specified network name is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We are connecting to a third party system (book easy) to import information in to our CMS. This was working fine until last week and throws the below error. I'm new to .net.. so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    [IOException: The format of the specified network name is invalid.
]
   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath) +7714920
   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +1162
   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +61
   System.Net.FileWebStream..ctor(FileWebRequest request, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare sharing, Int32 length, Boolean async) +65
   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint) +94

[WebException: The format of the specified network name is invalid.
]
   System.Net.FileWebResponse..ctor(FileWebRequest request, Uri uri, FileAccess access, Boolean asyncHint) +330
   System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponseCallback(Object state) +260

[WebException: The format of the specified network name is invalid.
]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +287
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address) +106
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(String address) +29
   CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.GetRemoteFile(String url) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:731
   CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.SetFeatureImage(ContentVersion cv, List`1 list) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:606
   CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.ImportOperatorData(ContentVersion operatorCV, Int32 operatorId) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:419
   CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.ImportOperators(List`1 operatorIds, ContentVersion parentCV) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:336
   CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.ProcessContent(ProcessContentDelegate`1 processDelegate, List`1 toProcess, ContentVersion cv) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:297
   CoA.Admin.WebUI.CoA_BookeasyOperatorAdmin.ProcessContent(ProcessContentDelegate`1 processDelegate, List`1 toProcess, ContentVersion cv) in C:\dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.Admin.WebUI\CoA_BookeasyOperatorAdmin.aspx.cs:411
   CoA.Admin.WebUI.CoA_BookeasyOperatorAdmin.CreateSelectedHere_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.Admin.WebUI\CoA_BookeasyOperatorAdmin.aspx.cs:193
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +110
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
```

This is the relevant code:-

```
#region CRUD

        public void ProcessContent<T>(ProcessContentDelegate<T> processDelegate, List<T> toProcess, ContentVersion cv)
        {
            //Only allow one thread to create at a time - that way ImportOperator() will catch any double-ups
            //Using same thread locker that is used to cache the remote operators for added safety
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (validation.Count == 0)
                {
                    processDelegate(toProcess, cv);
                }
            }
        }
        private ContentVersion CreateChildPage(ContentVersion parentCV, ObjectType ot)
        {
            ContentVersion new_cv = null;

            Content newPage = new Content();
            SessionUser su = _user;
            bool userCanCreateContent = AccessManager.GetInstance().CanPerformTask(su, "Create content");
            if (userCanCreateContent)
            {
                ItemPermission ip = ItemPermissionManager.GetItemPermissionByContentVersion(parentCV);
                bool canCreateType = (ip == null) ? true : ip.listObjectTypes.Contains<ObjectType>(ot);
                if (canCreateType)
                {
                    validation.AddRange(ContentManager.CreateNew(newPage, parentCV.objContent, ot, su, false));
                    if (validation.Count == 0)
                    {
                        new_cv = newPage.listVersions.LastOrDefault<ContentVersion>();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    validation.Add("You cannot create a page of the type \"" + ot.name + "\" here.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                validation.Add("You do not have permission to create new pages.");
            }
            return new_cv;
        }

        public void ImportOperators(List<int> operatorIds, ContentVersion parentCV)
        {
            foreach (int operatorId in operatorIds)
            {
                ImportOperator(operatorId, parentCV);
                if (validation.Count > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public void ImportOperators(List<BookeasyOperator> operators, ContentVersion parentCV)
        {
            foreach (BookeasyOperator o in operators)
            {
                ImportOperator(o.OperatorID, parentCV);
                if (validation.Count > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void ImportOperator(int operatorId, ContentVersion parentCV)
        {
            if (!cvsByBookeasyId.ContainsKey(operatorId))
            {
                ContentVersion new_cv = CreateChildPage(parentCV, ot);
                if (validation.Count > 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                ImportOperatorData(new_cv, operatorId);
            }
        }
        private void ImportOperatorData(ContentVersion operatorCV, int operatorId)
        {
            if (!operators.ContainsKey(operatorId))
            {
                validation.Add("The operator with the ID " + operatorId.ToString() + " does not seem to exist.");
                return;
            }
            ContentVersion c = operatorCV;
            BookeasyOperator o = operators[operatorId];

            DataField df_Body = GetDataField(c, "Body");
            DataField df_BookeasyOperatorID = GetDataField(c, "Bookeasy Operator ID");
            DataField df_IsAutoUpdatedFromBookEasy = GetDataField(c, "Is Auto-Updated from BookEasy");
            DataField df_FeatureImage = GetDataField(c, "Feature Image");
            DataField df_Summary = GetDataField(c, "Summary");
            DataField df_FirstName = GetDataField(c, "First Name");
            DataField df_Surname = GetDataField(c, "Surname");
            DataField df_BusinessName = GetDataField(c, "Business Name");
            DataField df_OpeningHours = GetDataField(c, "Opening Hours");
            DataField df_OpeningHoursDetails = GetDataField(c, "Opening Hours Details");
            DataField df_Location = GetDataField(c, "Location");
            DataField df_Email = GetDataField(c, "Email");
            DataField df_Website = GetDataField(c, "Website");
            DataField df_Phone = GetDataField(c, "Phone");
            DataField df_Fax = GetDataField(c, "Fax");
            DataField df_Mobile = GetDataField(c, "Mobile");
            DataField df_OperatorType = GetDataField(c, "Operator Type");
            DataField df_AccommodationGrouping = GetDataField(c, "Accommodation Grouping");
            DataField df_SettingAndAtmosphere = GetDataField(c, "Setting and Atmosphere");
            DataField df_Region = GetDataField(c, "Region");
            DataField df_BusinessGrouping = GetDataField(c, "Business Grouping");
            DataField df_Facilities = GetDataField(c, "Facilities");
            DataField df_LastUpdatedByBookEasy = GetDataField(c, "Last Updated by BookEasy");
            DataField df_IsMothership = GetDataField(c, "Is Mothership");

            DataField df_TariffFrom = GetDataField(c, "Tariff From");
            DataField df_TariffTo = GetDataField(c, "Tariff To");
            DataField df_DepartureTime = GetDataField(c, "Departure Time");
            DataField df_ArrivalTime = GetDataField(c, "Arrival Time");
            DataField df_StarRating = GetDataField(c, "Star Rating");
            DataField df_IsSelfRated = GetDataField(c, "Is Self Rated");
            DataField df_Policies = GetDataField(c, "Policies");

            DataField df_BookableTypes = GetDataField(c, "Bookable Types");
            DataField df_HideContactDetails = GetDataField(c, "Hide Contact Details");

            string content = OrDefault(o.PointOfDifference) + "\r\n\r\n" + OrDefault(o.Description);
            content = CleanContent(content);

            c.name = o.TradingName;

            df_Body.value = HtmlifyContent(content);
            df_BookeasyOperatorID.value = operatorId.ToString();
            df_IsAutoUpdatedFromBookEasy.value = "Yes";
            df_FeatureImage.value = SetFeatureImage(c, o.Pictures);
            df_Summary.value = SummariseContent(content);
            df_FirstName.value = OrDefault(o.FirstName);
            df_Surname.value = OrDefault(o.Surname);
            df_BusinessName.value = OrDefault(o.TradingName);
            df_OpeningHours.value = OrDefault(o.Hours);

            df_Email.value = OrDefault(o.Email);
            df_Website.value = OrDefault(o.Website);
            df_Phone.value = OrDefault(o.Telephone1);
            df_Fax.value = OrDefault(o.Facsimile);
            df_Mobile.value = OrDefault(o.Mobile);
            df_Facilities.value = ListToSeamlessString(o.Facilities);
            df_SettingAndAtmosphere.value = GetSettingAndAtmosphereAsSeamlessString(o);
            df_BusinessGrouping.value = GetBusinessTypesAsSeamlessString(o);
            df_IsMothership.value = (o.IsMothership) ? "Yes" : "No";
            df_LastUpdatedByBookEasy.value = GetSeamlessTime(o.DateModified);

            df_TariffFrom.value = OrDefault(o.TarriffFrom);
            df_TariffTo.value = OrDefault(o.TarriffTo);
            df_DepartureTime.value = OrDefault(o.DepartureTime);
            df_ArrivalTime.value = OrDefault(o.ArrivalTime);
            df_StarRating.value = GetStarRating(o.StarRating);
            df_IsSelfRated.value = (o.IsSelfRated) ? "Yes" : "No";
            df_Policies.value = CleanContent(o.Cancellation);

            df_BookableTypes.value = ListToSeamlessString(o.BookableTypes);
            df_HideContactDetails.value = (o.HideContactDetails) ? "Yes" : "No";

            if (o.OperatorDetails != null)
            {
                OperatorDetailsShort od = o.OperatorDetails;
                df_OperatorType.value = GetOperatorTypesAsSeamlessString(od.OperatorTypes);
                df_AccommodationGrouping.value = ListToSeamlessString(od.OperatorGroupings);
                df_Region.value = GetOperatorLocationsAsSeamlessString(od.Locations);
                df_Location.value = SetLocation(o.TradingName, o.ResidentialAddress, od.Latitude, od.Longitude);

            }
            if (df_OperatorType.value == "") df_OperatorType.value = GetOperatorTypesAsSeamlessString(o);
            if (df_AccommodationGrouping.value == "") df_AccommodationGrouping.value = GetAccommodationGroupingAsSeamlessString(o);
            if (df_Region.value == "") df_Region.value = GetOperatorLocationsAsSeamlessString(o);

            c.objTemplate = ct;


            validation.AddRange(ContentVersionManager.Save(c));
            validation.AddRange(WorkflowManager.SubmitItemVersionToStage(c, _user, "Created through Bookeasy Operator Import Manager", true, true, null, null, null, false));


        }

        public void UpdateOperators(List<int> operatorIds, ContentVersion ignoredForDelegate)
        {
            UpdateOperators(operatorIds);
        }
        private void UpdateOperators(List<int> operatorIds)
        {
            foreach (int operatorId in operatorIds)
            {
                UpdateOperator(operatorId);
                /*
                 * Actually Allow this to continue, even if one page fails - should be non-fatal and just report on errors
                if (validation.Count > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }*/
            }
        }
        private void UpdateOperator(int operatorId)
        {
            if (cvsByBookeasyId.ContainsKey(operatorId))
            {
                foreach (OperatorDecisionHelper odh in cvsByBookeasyId[operatorId])
                {
                    UpdateOperatorData(odh);
                    /*
                     * Actually Allow this to continue, even if one page fails - should be non-fatal and just report on errors
                    if (validation.Count > 0)
                    {
                        return;
                    }*/
                }
            }
        }
        private void UpdateOperatorData(OperatorDecisionHelper odh)
        {
            ContentVersion NewVersion = new ContentVersion();
            validation.AddRange(ContentVersionManager.MakeCopy(NewVersion, ContentVersionManager.Get(odh.ContentVersion.id), _user, false));
            NewVersion.sequence = odh.ContentVersion.sequence;
            NewVersion.objContentParent = odh.ContentVersion.objContentParent;
            NewVersion.versionNumber = odh.ContentVersion.versionNumber + 1;
            ImportOperatorData(NewVersion, odh.BookEasyOperatorId);
        }

        public void ArchiveOperators(List<Guid> cvIds, ContentVersion ignoredForDelegate)
        {
            ArchiveOperators(cvIds);
        }
        private void ArchiveOperators(List<Guid> cvIds)
        {
            foreach (Guid cvId in cvIds)
            {
                ArchiveOperator(cvId);
                if (validation.Count > 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        private void ArchiveOperator(Guid cvid)
        {
            ContentVersion cv = ContentVersionManager.Get(cvid);
            if (cv != null)
            {
                validation.AddRange(ContentManager.Archive(cv.objContent.id));
            }
        }

#endregion

#region Operator Content Management

        #region Location Management

        private string SetLocation(string name, string address, double lat, double lon)
        {
            if (name == null || address == null || name == "" || address == "" || lat == 0 || lon == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }
            string parentLink = "$" + _user.currentGroup.id.ToString() + "$" + "/Tools/Locations";
            string link = parentLink + "/" + FormatTools.StripAndReplaceURLUnfriendlyChars(name);
            ContentVersion LocationCv = ContentVersionManager.GetActiveByLink(link).FirstOrDefault<ContentVersion>();
            if (LocationCv == null)
            {
                ContentVersion parent_cv = ContentVersionManager.GetActiveByLink(parentLink).FirstOrDefault<ContentVersion>();
                if (parent_cv != null)
                {
                    LocationCv = CreateNewLocation(parent_cv, name, address, lat, lon);
                }
                else
                {
                    return "";
                }
            }

            return string.Concat(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(name), FormatTools.KEY_VALUE_PAIR_DELIMITER, LocationCv.link, FormatTools.KEY_VALUE_PAIR_DELIMITER, "newwindow");
            //return LocationCv.link;            
        }
        private ContentVersion CreateNewLocation(ContentVersion parent, string name, string address, double lat, double lon)
        {
            ObjectType ot = ObjectTypeManager.GetByName("Location");
            ContentVersion new_cv = CreateChildPage(parent, ot);

            DataField df_address = GetDataField(new_cv, "Location Street Address");
            DataField df_lat = GetDataField(new_cv, "Location Latitude");
            DataField df_lon = GetDataField(new_cv, "Location Longitude");
            try
            {
                df_address.value = address;
                df_lat.value = lat.ToString();
                df_lon.value = lon.ToString();
                new_cv.name = name;
                validation.AddRange(ContentVersionManager.Save(new_cv));
                validation.AddRange(WorkflowManager.SubmitItemVersionToStage(new_cv, _user, "Created through Location panel", true, true, null, null, null, false));
                return new_cv;
            }
            catch
            {

            }
            return null;

        }

        #endregion

        #region Feature Image Management

        private string SetFeatureImage(ContentVersion cv, List<string> list)
        {
            if (list == null || list.Count == 0) return "";
            string RemoteURL = list[0];
            string LocalURL = "";
            Uri uri = new Uri(RemoteURL);
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
            MemoryStream file = GetRemoteFile(RemoteURL);
            if (file != null)
            {
                LocalURL = WriteOutputSeamlessFile(cv, filename, file);
            }
            return LocalURL;
        }
        private string WriteOutputSeamlessFile(ContentVersion cv, string filename, MemoryStream ms)
        {
            Seamless.CMS.File OutputFile;
            string LocalURL = "";
            bool CreateNewFile = true;
            ObjectType ot = ObjectTypeManager.GetByName("Image");

            List<FileVersion> fvList = new List<FileVersion>();
            foreach (Seamless.CMS.File file in cv.listFilesOwned)
            {
                FileVersion fv = FileVersionManager.GetFileLatest(file.id);
                if (fv != null)
                {
                    fvList.Add(fv);
                }
            }

            FileVersion outputFv = fvList.FirstOrDefault<FileVersion>(pfv => pfv.name == filename);
            if (outputFv != null)
            {
                string fileID = outputFv.id.ToString();
                string physicalLocation = CMSSettings.physicalAssetDirFile + fileID;
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(physicalLocation))
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(physicalLocation, FileMode.Open);
                    HashAlgorithm ha = (HashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName("SHA1");
                    Int64 fsh = BitConverter.ToInt64(ha.ComputeHash(fs), 0);
                    Int64 msh = BitConverter.ToInt64(ha.ComputeHash(ms), 0);
                    CreateNewFile = (fsh != msh);
                }
                if (CreateNewFile)
                {
                    cv.listFilesOwned.Remove(outputFv.objFile);
                }
            }

            if (CreateNewFile)
            {
                OutputFile = FileManager.CreateNew((Folder)null, _user, false, ot);
                OutputFile.listVersions[0].name = filename;
                OutputFile.listVersions[0].objCheckedOutBy = null;

                string fileID = OutputFile.listVersions[0].id.ToString();
                string physicalLocation = CMSSettings.physicalAssetDirFile + fileID;
                try
                {
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(physicalLocation, FileMode.Create);
                    ms.WriteTo(fs);
                    LocalURL = FinaliseOutputFile(cv, OutputFile, filename);
                }
                catch
                {
                    ExceptionManager.Log("Could not generate feature image for: " + cv.name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                LocalURL = getURLFromFilenameAndID(outputFv.objFile.id, filename);
            }

            return LocalURL;
        }
        private Seamless.CMS.File GetOutputSeamlessFile(ContentVersion cv, string filename)
        {
            ObjectType ot = ObjectTypeManager.GetByName("Image");
            Seamless.CMS.File OutputFile;
            List<FileVersion> fvList = new List<FileVersion>();
            foreach (Seamless.CMS.File file in cv.listFilesOwned)
            {
                FileVersion fv = FileVersionManager.GetFileLatest(file.id);
                if (fv != null)
                {
                    fvList.Add(fv);
                }
            }
            FileVersion outputFv = fvList.FirstOrDefault<FileVersion>(pfv => pfv.name == filename);
            if (outputFv != null)
            {
                cv.listFilesOwned.Remove(outputFv.objFile);
            }
            OutputFile = FileManager.CreateNew((Folder)null, _user, false, ot);
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].name = filename;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].objCheckedOutBy = null;
            return OutputFile;
        }
        private string FinaliseOutputFile(ContentVersion cv, Seamless.CMS.File OutputFile, string filename)
        {
            SessionUser su = _user;

            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(CMSSettings.physicalAssetDirFile + OutputFile.listVersions[0].id.ToString());
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].size = (int)fi.Length;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].objWorkflow = null;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].isPublished = true;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].activateDate = DateTime.Now;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].deactivateDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
            OutputFile.listVersions[0].isRolledback = false;
            FileVersionManager.Save(OutputFile.listVersions[0]);
            OutputFile.objGroup = su.currentGroup;
            OutputFile.objOwnerContentVersion = cv;
            OutputFile.isArchived = false;
            FileManager.Save(OutputFile);

            if (!cv.listFilesOwned.Contains(OutputFile))
            {
                cv.listFilesOwned.Add(OutputFile);
            }
            return getURLFromFilenameAndID(OutputFile.id, filename);
        }
        private string getURLFromFilenameAndID(Guid guid, string filename)
        {
            return "files/" + guid.ToString() + "/" + filename + FormatTools.KEY_VALUE_PAIR_DELIMITER.ToString();
        }
        private MemoryStream GetRemoteFile(string url)
        {
            MemoryStream file;
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                file = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(url));
            }
            finally
            {
                client.Dispose();
            }
            return file;
        }

        #endregion
```

Comment: You need to post the code in which you are getting exception, just showing the stack trace is not enough.

Comment: CoA.BookEasy.OperatorManager.GetRemoteFile(String url) in d:\Dev\ArmadaleVisitorCentre\CoA.BookEasy.OperatorImport\OperatorManager.cs:731

Comment: @Rex Just updated the question with the relevant code

Comment: Check the the value of `url` in the line `file = new MemoryStream(client.DownloadData(url));`. Does this path exist?